# List of IPv4 addresses separated by a comma regex?

Tags: regex

I have a regex to match IPv4 addresses :

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

Now I want the same regex but for list of IPv4 addresses separated by a comma

Example (with impossibility to end the string by a comma):

```
172.24.64.100.0,172.25.64.100.0,172.26.64.100
```

How I can do it ?

Thanks,

Comment: This may work `^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:,(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))*$`

Comment: Remove the anchors (`^` and `$`), let's say `<x>` is the result that matches a single item. Then `<x>(?:,<x>)*` will match a non-empty sequence of such items, and `<x>(?:,<x>)+` would match such a sequence with at least two items/one comma. Add the anchors back around that regex if you need to match a whole string rather than parts of it

Comment: @Eraklon a little bit long but yes it works very well, thanks !

Comment: @DeadlockState Np. The general idea is `(?:<pattern>)(?:,<pattern>)*`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex if the language supports the PCRE (PHP) engine. Note that it uses subroutines.

```
(?=(25[0-5]|2[1-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9])){0}(?=((?1)(?:\.(?1)){3})){0}(?=(?2)(?:,(?2))*$)(?2)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Phc8uL/3/)

The regex performs the following operations.

*Define capture group 1*

```
(?=           # begin positive lookahead
  (           # begin capture group 1
    25[0-5]   # match 250-255
    |         # or
    2[0-4]\d  # match 200-249
    |         # or
    1\d{2}    # match 100-199
    |         # or
    [1-9]\d   # match 10-99
    |         # or
    [1-9]     # match 1-9
  )           # end capture group 1
)             # end positive lookahead
{0}           # execute postive lookahead zero times
```

*Define capture group 2*

```
(?=           # begin positive lookahead
  (           # begin cap grp 2
    (?1)      # execute cap grp 1 instructions
    (?:       # begin non-cap grp
      \.(?1)  # match '.' then execute cap grp 1 instructions
    {3}       # end non-cap grp   
  )           # end cap grp 2
)             # end positive lookahead
{0}           # execute postive lookahead zero times
```

*Confirm the string contains only comma-separated valid IPv4 addresses*

```
(?=           # begin positive lookahead
  (?2)        # execute cap grp 2 instructions
  (?:         # begin non-cap grp 
    ,(?2)     # match ',' then execute cap grp 2 instructions 
  )           # end non-cap grp
  *           # execute non-cap grp 0+ times
  $           # match end of line
)             # end positive lookahead
```

*Match IPv4 addresses*

```
(?2)          # execute cap grp 2 instructions
```

Some regex engines that support subroutines (or *subexpressions*) may have a syntax different syntax. Ruby, for example, uses `\g<1>` instead of `(?1)`. One can alternatively use named capture groups. PCRE uses `(?P>sue)` for the capture group named 'sue'. See [this discussion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) for details.

If one does not wish to use subroutines, or if the language's regex engine does not support them (Python being one, I understand) one could replace, for example `(?1)` with the contents of capture group 1:

```
25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9]
```

Naturally, the regex would increase in size greatly (consider the replacement for `(?2)`). Another advantage of using subroutines is that each subroutine can be tested individually.

**Non-regex methods**

I viewed developing the regex above as an exercise (and an  opportunity to introduce some readers to regex subroutines), but I would not advise that approach in favor of the use of normal language tools. In Ruby, for example, only a few lines of code are needed, as shown below. Those not familiar with Ruby should be able to get the gist of what is happening in the code.

```
require 'ipaddr'
```

```
def ipv4s(str)
  str.split(',').map do |s|
    i = IPAddr.new(s)
    raise ArgumentError, "'#{s}' is not an IP address" if i.nil?
    raise ArgumentError, "'#{s}' is not an IPv4 address" unless i.ipv4?
    s
  end
end
```

```
ipv4s("172.24.64.100,172.25.64.100,172.26.64.100")
  #=> "2001:0DB8:AC10:FE01:0000:0000:0000:0000"
ipv4s("172.24.64.100, 172.25.64.100,172.26.64.100")
  #=> IPAddr::InvalidAddressError ( 172.25.64.100)
                                   ^
ipv4s("172.2403.64.100,172.25.64.100,172.26.64.100")
  #=> IPAddr::InvalidAddressError (72.2403.64.100)
                                      ^^^^
ipv4s("cat 172.24.64.100,172.25.64.100,172.26.64.100")
  #=> IPAddr::InvalidAddressError (cat 172.24.64.100)
                                   ^^^^ 
ipv4s("172.24.64.100,172.25.64.275,172.26.64.100")
  #=> IPAddr::InvalidAddressError (172.25.64.275)
                                             ^^^
```

Comment: You can remove your comment as I've edited my answer to address that. I suggest you edit your question to clarify that the anchors are required. Also, in your example, the first two IPv4 addresses are not of the form `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.